# Restricted Cubic Spline output in R rms package after cph

Tags: r, cubic-spline

I am developing a COX regression model in R.
The model I am currently using is as follows

```
fh <- cph(S ~ rcs(MPV,4) + rcs(age,3) + BMI + smoking + hyperten + gender +
    rcs(FVCPP,3) + TLcoPP, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, surv=TRUE, time.inc=2*52)
```

If I then want to look at this with

```
print(fh, latex = TRUE)
```

I get 3 `coefs/SE/Wald` etc for `MPV (MVP, MVP' and MVP'')` and 2 for `age (age, age')`.
Could someone please explain to me what these outputs are? i.e. I believe they are to do with the restricted cubic splines I have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `rcs(MPV,4)`, you define the number of knots to use in the spline; in this case 4. Similarly, `rcs(age,3)` defines a spline with 3 knots. Due to identifiability constraints, 1 knot from each spline is subtracted out. You can think of this as defining an intercept for each spline. So `rcs(Age,3)` is a linear combination of 2 nonlinear basis functions and an intercept, while `rcs(MPV,4)` is a linear combination of 3 nonlinear basis functions and an intercept, i.e.,

[image]

and

[image]

In the notation above, what you get out from the print statement are the regression coefficients [image] and [image], with corresponding standard errors, p-values etc. The intercepts [image] and [image] are typically set to zero, but they are important, because without them, the model fitting routine how have no idea of where on the y-axis to constrain the splines.

As a final note, you might actually be more interested in the output of `summary(fh)`.